# I'm not sure why I'm getting the error: "IndexError: string index out of range"

Tags: python

I'm doing the CS50 course and this is a task to remove all vowels. I'm not sure what is going on, but my program gets stuck at line 4 saying there is an `IndexError` and I'm not sure what is the exact error.

```
text = input('Input: ')
index = 0
for _ in range (len(text)):
    letter = text[index]
    newletter = letter.lower()
    if newletter == "a" or newletter == "e" or newletter == "i" or newletter == "o" or newletter == "u":
        text = text.replace(letter, "", 1)
    index = index + 1
print("Output: "+user)
```

Comment: `range (len(text))` is created once at the very start. It doesn't update as `text` is reassigned. Think about what happens to the size of `text` as you remove letters from it, and what values `index` will take on. Also, there's little point in throwing away the iteration variable using `_` then maintaining a separate `index` variable. You might as well just use the elements that `range` produces.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `range(len(text))`, that creates the `range` item right at that point.  If the string was 10 characters long, you'll have a `range(10)` that runs from 0 to 9.

When you delete characters from the string, that doesn't change the range.  The range will still run from 0 to 9, even though the string is now only 7 characters long.  You might consider:

```
while index < len(text):
```

because that will be evaluated on every iteration.  HOWEVER, a much better plan is to build a NEW string that only has the elements you want.  It's never good practice to modify something you're iterating through.

```
new = ''
for c in text:
    if c not in 'aeiou':
        new += c
print("Output:", new)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. writing a new string variable worked wonders.

Answer (score 0):

Problem is that, you're using range(). Correct way is:

```
for a in text:
    print(a)
    letter = a
```

Comment: Don't use `_`, [that's conventionally a throwaway name](/q/5893163/4518341).

Comment: @wjandrea ok, thanks for your correction :D

Comment: Happy to help! Also, why bother having two names for the same thing when you could just do `for letter in text:`? You should also mention that you can (and should) remove `index` from the code.